# How do I explain boolean into English?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have a question
that deals with Booleans and || or. I was able to write this program correctly, but I am having trouble putting into English why when you have both inputs as false, the answer is false. If it is not raining or it is not snowing, the weather can still be bad.

INPUT[1] is true if it is raining.

INPUT[2] is true if it is snowing.

Write a program that returns true if the weather is bad. (We will consider it's bad weather if it's not sunny).

Tip: you can return boolean variables or expressions directly, sometimes an if else statement is not needed.

var Rain = INPUT[1]

var Snow = INPUT[2]

return Rain || Snow

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a programming language, so just speaking logically you have the following criteria:

`Rain = TRUE` if it is raining

`Snow = TRUE` if it is snowing

and you have the following definition of Weather:

```
Weather = Rain || Snow
```

In this question, there are no other variables that can impact the `Weather` variable, which means that the weather has to be good (i.e. `Weather = FALSE`) if it's both not raining (`Rain = FALSE`) and not snowing (`Snow = FALSE`).

Regarding your comment:

> If it is not raining or it is not snowing, the weather can still be
> bad.

That is still possible because when you say:

> If it is not raining **OR** it is not snowing

this is just an `or` statement. The other condition can still be `TRUE` in which case Weather will also be `TRUE`.